# MySQL returned an empty result set

Tags: php, mysql

i dont understand why mysql table return empty result set, the code seems okay.
the response from mysql: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0010 sec)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "myexcel";

// Create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);


if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen( $file, "r");
        while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle, 3000, ",")) !== false)
        {
            $id = $fileop[0];
            $name = $fileop[1];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO csv (id, name) VALUES ('$id', '$name')";
        }

        if ($sql)
        {
            echo "OK";
        }
}
?>

<html>
<body>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file"> 
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no `mysqli_query` anywhere ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to query:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO csv (id, name) VALUES ('$id', '$name')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add mysqli_query and put your `if condition` inside `while` loop.... And i could not see any `form` tag in your code ???  I have added here with `post method`

```
   ?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "myexcel";

    // Create connection
    $connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);


    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
            $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $handle = fopen( $file, "r");
            while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle, 3000, ",")) !== false)
            {
                $id = $fileop[0];
                $name = $fileop[1];
                $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO csv (id, name) VALUES ('$id', '$name')");

            if ($sql)
            {
                echo "Ok. Inserted <br>";
            }
            }


    }
    ?>

    <html>
    <body>
      <form method="POST"> // add this
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file"> 
     <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```