# java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set. when query return only 1 row

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

in this code i am trying to get a row from the id in for lopp variable
and printing it into a labels which are created on the basis of count 
though count is less then the total number of rows in the database the the returns a correct ans when i executed it in mysql.
but when i use the rs.getstring("concept name") in the last line to get the contents of "concept name" column i get empty result set error.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/niitdb","root","");

for(pos=0; pos<7; pos++){

     SQL = "SELECT `concept name` FROM `concepts " +course+ "` where `concept id` = " + pos+1;   
     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
     rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
     rs.next();
     Cname[cnt] = new JLabel(rs.getString("concept name")); // error is on this line 
}
```

Comment: The most likely explanation here is that your query returns no records.  Can you try running the query from Workbench directly?

Comment: i tried the query in phpmyadmin and it returned 1 row which i was expecting .

Comment: when i replace the 'rs.getString("concept name")' with some default value it executes correctly

Comment: thanks Tim and EJP for your responses
i solved it 
the problem was at pos+1
including it into brackets solved the error
   SQL = "SELECT `concept name` FROM `concepts " +course+ "` where `concept id` = " + (pos+1);

Comment: So everybody was right and the result set was empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL returned an empty result set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800908/mysql-returned-an-empty-result-set)

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC driver may not handle the column name with blanks correctly. I would try it as

```
SELECT `concept name` as concept_name FROM ...
```

and then

```
if (rs.next())
{
    Cname[cnt] = new JLabel(rs.getString("concept_name"));
}
```

as you should not call `rs.next()` without testing the result, and only proceeding to get column values if it was true.

Comment: Thanks EJP 
but changing the coulmn name still didnt work
and previously i testest rs.next() them proceeded but in that case no label was created
even though the query return a single row with the primary key 'concept id'

Comment: That would indicate that it was `false`, and that no rows were returned. *That* is the problem you need to investigate.

Comment: @ejp Actually the problem is that no _columns_ are being returned.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, the actual problem is that the result set is empty, which means no rows.

Comment: Choice of words: There may have been matching records, but since no columns were selected hence the result set was empty.